# Styling page when accordion/tabs is open or closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, accordion

I am building a Tabs menu using [jellekralt/Responsive-Tabs](https://github.com/jellekralt/Responsive-Tabs). Now I want to change the page background when the tabs are open, I created the class 'blurredbg' with the new background. I used the following code but this works only once for each tabs, someone can help me? thanks.

```
$('.r-tabs-tab').on('click', function() {
$("body").addClass("blurredbg");
// IF TABS = ACTIVE
$('.r-tabs-state-active').on('click' , function() {
// IF ACTIVE IS CLOSED
if ( ! $('.r-tabs-tab').hasClass('.r-tabs-state-active')) {
        $("body").removeClass("blurredbg");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
$('.r-tabs-tab').on('click', function() {
    $(document.body).addClass("blurredbg");
    // IF ACTIVE IS CLOSED
    if ( ! $(this).hasClass('r-tabs-state-active')) {
        $(document.body).removeClass("blurredbg");
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answers, unfortunately still does not work, nothing happens, I did some testing, the problem is the condition 'if', I removed 'if' and background change, but obviously when i close the tabs no returns normal. before with condition 'if' in the the function $('.r-tabs-state-active').on('click' , function() { }); it works once for tabs.

Comment: I replaced on-click with focusout but does not work, I do not understand why it does not work the condition 'if' inside the function, ho provato anche questo codice, but nothing:

Comment: $('.r-tabs-tab').on('click', function() {
           
            if ($(this).hasClass('.r-tabs-state-active')) {
               $(document.body).addClass("blurredbg");
            } else {
               $(document.body).removeClass("blurredbg");
            }

           });
          });

Comment: I did not see the error, Now it works, thank you very much, you saved me :D